# How to convert ``my_list`` into "ccc-mmm-iii-nnn-ggg" in one line?

Tags: python-3.x, list

How to convert `my_list` into "ccc-mmm-iii-nnn-ggg" in one line ? I cant write `my_list = "ccc-mmm-iii-nnn-ggg"`
but the output has to be my_list = ['ccc', 'mmm', 'iii', 'nnn', 'ggg']

(sorry I am absolute beginner)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option:

```
my_str = 'ccc-mmm-iii-nnn-ggg'
my_lst = my_str.split('-')
```

`my_lst` is your desired output:

```
['ccc', 'mmm', 'iii', 'nnn', 'ggg']
```